# When will $M$ be an $R_n$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Problem: Let $n$ be an integer and let $R_n\subset \mathbb{Q}$ consist of rational numbers whose denominator is divisible by primes dividing $n$. Let $m$ be a different integer, and consider $M$, the cyclic group with $m$ elements. When will $M$ be a $R_n$-module?

Claim: $M$ is a $R_n-$module when $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Case 1: $\gcd(m,n)=1$.
So $R_n=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]=\{\frac{a}{b} \mid b=p_1 p_2\cdots p_k, p_i|n \,\forall i\}$. If $\gcd(m,n)=1,$ I want to show that $\frac{a}{b}x\in M$ for any $x\in M$. $$\frac{a}{b}x=\frac{ax}{p_1 p_2\cdots p_k}.$$ Since $m, n$ are coprime, then that means the don't share any prime factors so for each $p_i\in M, \exists v_i\in M$ s.t. $p_iv_i=1\implies \frac{1}{p_i}=v_i$ in $M$. Now that scaling by $\frac{1}{n}$ is well defined in $M$, then I can rewrite  $$\frac{ax}{p_1 p_2\cdots p_k}=ax\Pi_{i=1}^{n} v_i\in \mathbb{Z}.$$ So thus $\frac{a}{b}x\in M$ since $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}-$module.

Case 2: $\gcd(m,n)\neq 1$.

Now $\frac{a}{b}x=\frac{ax}{p_1 p_2\cdots p_k}$. There is at least one $p_i$ s.t. there is no $v_i$ in $M$ s.t. $p_i$ is a unit. So $\frac{a}{b}x\notin \mathbb{Z}\implies \frac{a}{b}x\notin M$.

I'm wondering if it's okay that I treated $M$ like $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ in this case? I was given that $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}-$module. I'm questioning this implication: $p_iv_i=1\implies \frac{1}{p_i}=v_i$. Could someone provide feedback on my argument please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abelian group $ M $ has a natural structure as a $ R_n $-module if and only if multiplication by $ n : M \to M $ is invertible. In particular, when $ M $ is cyclic of order $m$, multiplication by $n$ is invertible if and only if $ \operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=1 $.

The reason for the above boils down to the fact that $R_n$ is $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]$, i. e. the ring $ \mathbb{Z} $ with an inverse of the element $n$ adjoined. This ring has a universal property, namely that a homomorphism of rings $\varphi \colon \mathbb{Z} \to A $ factors through a map $ \mathbb{Z}[1/n] \to A $ if and only if $ \varphi(n) $ is invertible in $ A $. Interpreting a $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]$-module structure as a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[1/n] \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) $, the result is immediate.

To put this into a more general context, the process of passing from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]$ is known as *localization*. For a commutative ring $ A $ and multiplicative subset $ S \subseteq A $ one form the localized ring $ A[S^{-1}] $, informally described as the ring $ A $ with inverses of every element of $ S $ adjoined. One then has the general result that the category of $ A[S^{-1}]$-modules is equivalent to the category of $ A $-modules on which multiplication by every element of $ S $ is invertible.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure that I understand what $A$ is int this case. Also what is $End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ adn A[S^{-1}]$? I take it that I'm on the right track since that's what I've argued so far.